# C# How can I make sure to execute awaitable operations in a single thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, uwp, async-await, deadlock

I am building an UWP application, which obviously contains several awaitable calls to async methods.

In one of the event handlers I need to make sure that the chain of calls is performed in a single thread.

I tried to make my "sync" version of the async methods that I need by waiting and getting the result, something like this:

```
public static T Sync<T>(this Task<T> task)
{
    if (task == null)
        return default(T);
    return task.ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Or even more brutal:

```
    public static T Sync<T>(this Task<T> task)
    {
        if (task == null)
            return default(T);
        task.Wait();
        return task.Result;
    }
```

But I came out with the deadlock problem described in several other blogs, because I am running on the UI Thread.

Is there a way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: If the async calls use `.ConfigureAwait(false)`, there's nothing you can do. If they don't, their continuation will run on the UI thread, so you're already on a single thread

Comment: I am not afraid of the continuation, which I want to be in the UI Thread, I want to avoid that while I am awaiting, another async call changes my state. Basically I want to wrap my full call chain an a single thread operation.

Comment: The async code will use the SynchronizationContext.Current property, so you could make a custom class which handles the Post/Send methods in your thread, but as far as I know the UWP framework already has a custom Context to run all the async code in a (single) UI thread, so I don't understand your problem? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make sure to execute awaitable operations in a single thread

As others noted, `async`/`await` on a UI thread by default *will* execute all continuations on a single thread.

> I want to avoid that while I am awaiting, another async call changes my state.

The *proper* solution for this is to fix your logic. Any alternative - particularly, making the UI thread nonresponsive - will degrade your user experience and may prevent your app from being accepted in the store.

That said, if you're *absolutely sure* you want to go down that path rather than fixing your code in the first place, you have two main options:

1. Make all your code synchronous. It'll run on the UI thread and block it, as desired.
2. Run a nested message loop. I'm not sure if this is supported on UWP; you *might* be able to get something working using my [`AsyncContext`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx/5.0.0-pre-05).

Again, *both* of these solutions will make your UI nonresponsive, degrading your user experience and possibly causing store rejections.

Answer (score 0):

If all you care about is serializing access to state (i.e. you only want one thread at a time modifying state), you can achieve this by using one of the many synchronization primitives built into .NET.

One of the simplest tools is the [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) statement.

Of course this will have the side effect of blocking your `Task`s, which may not ideal for your application. But there are some available implementations for ["async" locks](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLock).

Comment: Thanks @Joseph, but unfortunately it is not that easy: whenever in my code there is an await call, I see in the tasks list that a new task is created and started. This makes my chain multi-thread, which is the thing that I want to avoid.

Comment: The await call has to run in a task, there is no other wait for it to work, because your current thread code continues after the call. BUT the task use "callbacks" to run the actual code and these "callbacks" are run in the SynchronizationContext.Current Context, the "default" context can run in a different task/thread, but most UI frameworks (for example WPF) set a custom context so that all task callback will run in the (main) UI thread, so every single code of the async/wait "chain" will run in the UI thread too (by the task callbacks)

Comment: _"whenever in my code there is an await call, I see in the tasks list that a `new task` is created and started. This makes my chain `multi-thread`"_ - A `Task` is a higher level concept and **not** a thread.  Two `Task`s may or may not be executed in the same thread